# How to inherit from two types and use them as single class?

Tags: c#

There are types in a third party library that look like this:

```cs
public interface IInterfaceLib
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeBasicClassLib 
{
    //Some functionality here...
}

public class SomeClassLib : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib
{ 
    //Some functionality here...
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

I defined my own type which inherits from them:

```cs
public abstract class MyExtendedClass : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

Which does not add any functionality. It only "joins" them in hierarchy. I want to be able to use `SomeClassLib` as `MyExtendedClass`:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Cannot convert types.
    MyExtendedClass myObject = new SomeClassLib();
}
```

In other words I want to enforce some objects to be both `IInterfaceLib` and `SomeBasicClassLib` and still be able to use types similar to `SomeClassLib` from library. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you want `MyExtendedClass myObject = new SomeClassLib();` over `SomeClassLib myObject = new SomeClassLib();` or `MyExtendedClass myObject = new MyExtendedClass ();` or `SomeClassLib myObject = new MyExtendedClass ();`?

Comment: `public abstract class MyExtendedClass : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib` The fundamental issue here is that your hierarchy is the wrong way around. For things to work the way you want, then it would need to be `public class SomeBasicClassLib: MyExtendedClass , IInterfaceLib` which is unlikely to be possible if `SomeBasicClassLib` is a third party lib.

Comment: Have you considered composition over inheritance? Or extension methods?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You write that you _"want to be able to use `SomeClassLib` as `MyExtendedClass`"_, but in your code example, the `MyExtendedClass` is _not_ derived from `SomeClassLib`, so how do you expect that to even work? It doesn't help that you also write that you _"want to enforce some objects to be both `IInterfaceLib` and `SomeBasicClass`"_, but don't tell us what `SomeBasicClass` is at all (there's no such type in any of the code you posted).

Comment: Because I want one type which all types that implement <code>IInterfaceLib</code> and inherit from <code>IBasicClassLib</code> are assignable to. (there are more than one). Unfortunately there is not such type in library. All types I'm interested in inherit from both of them separately.

Comment: I considered composition but that would require a lot of wrapping already existing methods and I tried to avoid it. I guess that is the way to go, unfortunately.

Comment: @Shanie: _"You could imagine some fancy compiler that could handle this sort of thing"_ -- well, assuming the OP could even describe their problem in a way that would allow someone to fully understand what they want to do, no...it seems unlikely that _any_ C# compiler would accomplish the desired goal. The C# language specifically prohibits multiple inheritance (which is what it _seems_ like _maybe_ the OP wants here), so it wouldn't matter how fancy the compiler got, it couldn't do this. More to the point though, my comment to the OP is not about whether the question is "reasonable" or ...

Comment: ... not, but rather about whether the question is even _comprehensible_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What I'm trying to achieve is not multiple inheritance. I'm sorry if my question seems incomprehensible.

Comment: Have you tried using extension methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't

As far as C# is oncerned `MyExtendedClass` could do something that `SomeBasicClassLib` doesn't do. You could add more stuff to it on top of what you've inherited or implemented;

C# is expecting something on the right hand side of that equals to be able to do, at a minimum, all the things that `MyExtendedClass` can do.

C# compiler can't be sure that you didn't add anything else to `MyExtendedClass`.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved (kind of) what I wanted by specyfing type constraints everywhere I would use class similar to `SomeClassLib` :

```cs
public static void Main<T>(string[] args) where T : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib
{
    T myObject = new SomeClassLib();
}
```

This way any object that implements `IInterfaceLib` and inherits from `SomeBasicClassLib` is assignable to `T`, inlcuding my own types that derives from them, also `T` provides functionalities from both types.

Comment: This is utterly pointless. It gives you nothing over `var myObject = new SomeClassLib();`.

Comment: @mjwills I provided a really bad example. As I said in original question there are different classes that inherit separately from `IInterfaceLib` and `SomeBasicClassLib` - what I meant by that is there are classes in library : `SomeClassLib1 : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib { }` , `SomeClassLib2 : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib { }` etc. Let's say I want some static method that can take any of these as parameter and use their funcionality in it's body.

Comment: I tried to achieve it with inheritance by creating `MyExtendedClass` and then method signature would look something like this: `public static MyMethod(MyExtendedClass c)` since I didn't add any funcionality in the class I thought compiler would be ok with passing any of `SomeClassLibX` as parameter, but it is not. What I want is simply achievable by type constraints and method signature would look like this: `public static MyMethod(T p) where T : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib`.

Comment: Did you try using extension methods? I'll be honest, I am surprised your answer (as written) even _compiles_.

Comment: `I want is simply achievable by type constraints and method signature would look like this: public static MyMethod(T p) where T : SomeBasicClassLib, IInterfaceLib` What is the benefit of doing that over `public static MyMethod(SomeClassLib p)` and having `MyExtendedClass` inherit from `SomeClassLib`?